# R Leaflet plot ship direction

Tags: r, leaflet, markers, direction

I want to plot ships and its direction on the map using R Leaflet.

I tried to represent a ship as a circle and its direction with a line from the center as in the following picture.

[image]

The problem is that when zooming out the direction is lost (see picture below) because the circles maintain their size regardless of zoom but the lines do not.

[image]

For the circles I am using addCircleMarkers() function. For the lines I am using addPolylines(). addCircleMarkers() maintains its size regardless of zoom level but addPolylines() does not.

Are there any alternatives I could use to represent direction?.
I think about using an icon and rotating it using the [addAwesomeMarkers()](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html) function. The problem with this approach is that it also adds a marker but I just want the icon.

The ideal solution would be to have a line (or arrow) with size not dependent on zoom level or to be able to use an icon and rotate it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020079/icon-rotation-in-leaflet-package) is a related question for rotating an icon but seems hacky and not sure if it can be extended to more icons (the example uses 1) with different angles each.

Comment: any joy on this problem? I am looking to do exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I think that `addAwesomeMarkers()` is not that bad. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54282008/5193830) you can combine it with an `"arrow-up"` icon and was satisfactory for me. Otherwise, can try to use `iconList()` function (you find an example in [this documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html)), defining a series of rotated images/icons corresponding to several rotation classes.